# i18n for meta tags in Rails (FB open graph tags to be specific)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am looking to start supporting different languages with my website. Currently, we have Facebook Open Graph tags for English. If someone in Korea visits our site, they will view our content in Korean. If they decide to share this site to FB, the open graph tags should show Korean so we are looking to localize it.

In application.html.erb, I just put in:

```
<%= t '.meta_description_html' %>
```

Then in en.yml and ko.yml, I just enter:

```
<meta property="og:description" name="description" content="Description content.">
```

It works but is there a better way I should be implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Better you could use like:

```
<meta property="og:description" name="description" content="<%=t 'meta_description_html'%>">
```

This will look more clearly.